# Fun roulette ellipse image rotation (not 360)

Tags: wpf, rotation

I am creating fun roulette game where I am trying to rotate eclipse with wheel image inside on its axis (but not 360 degree). Right now, some problem with its rotation, its not rotating as per my requirement. If you will run below code with images attached also. you will get my requirement.

Pls set your screen resolution i.e. Height="1024" Width="768" for understanding my exact requirement. I am also attaching images here. one is background image and another is wheel image.

I am stuck on this from last one week. Any help will be appreciable. Thanks in advance.

```
     Title="MainWindow" Height="1024" Width="768"  
     WindowStyle="None"   
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="ball">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="360" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Image/fun_roulette.jpg" />
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


    <Ellipse Name="ball" Stroke="Black"                                                       
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="370" Height="200" 
             Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Opacity=".4" 
             Margin="0,30,0,0" 
              >
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup >
                <ScaleTransform  />
                <SkewTransform  />
                <RotateTransform Angle="45" CenterX="0" CenterY="0"  />
                <TranslateTransform />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Image/Roullette_Wheel.jpg"   />
        </Ellipse.Fill>
        <Ellipse.BitmapEffect>
            <BevelBitmapEffect BevelWidth="0" />
        </Ellipse.BitmapEffect>
        <Ellipse.BitmapEffectInput>
            <BitmapEffectInput />
        </Ellipse.BitmapEffectInput>
    </Ellipse>
</Grid>
```

Download Background Image from here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByTbA6S0c1TaZEo2akgtQjVCbjQ/view?usp=sharing

Download Wheel Image from here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByTbA6S0c1TaY1JzazhudDkzMjA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want the ellipse to rotate ***exactly*** at the position of the static disc in the background image. Also because of a little 3D effect (perspective effect), rotating the ellipse normally would not be able to produce the desired result. You can try using some 3D feature in WPF but it's some kind of overkill because we still have another choice.

Instead of rotating the whole ellipse, you can just rotate the `ImageBrush`. I've tried your code and tweaking it a little with some modifications and finally the effect seems to be what you want. Here is the code:

```
<Window.Resources>
 <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames RepeatBehavior="Forever" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" Storyboard.TargetName="rot">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="360" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>        
 </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
  <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
  </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<Grid>  
 <Grid.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Image/fun_roulette.jpg" />
 </Grid.Background>
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

 <Ellipse Name="ball" Stroke="Black" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.8"
          Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Opacity=".4" 
          Margin="6,0,0,0">    
    <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
      <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".195" ScaleY=".45"/>
    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Image/Roullette_Wheel.jpg">
           <ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
              <TransformGroup >                                
                <RotateTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" x:Name="rot"/>
                <SkewTransform/>                
                <TranslateTransform />
              </TransformGroup>
           </ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
        </ImageBrush>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
    <Ellipse.BitmapEffect>
        <BevelBitmapEffect BevelWidth="0" />
    </Ellipse.BitmapEffect>
    <Ellipse.BitmapEffectInput>
        <BitmapEffectInput />
    </Ellipse.BitmapEffectInput>
 </Ellipse>
</Grid>
```

You should copy and try this exact code, try scanning it for some differences from your original code.

Comment: Thank you King for the valuable solution. I implemented your idea and eventually my problem is solved now.. :-)